# How to customize toolbar in Navigation Drawer activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

After creating a Navigation Drawer activity in my Android Studio project I want to add a search view into the toolbar instead of my app name. How do I do it? Can the toolbar be customized based on my needs or creation of custom toolbar is required?

[image: Navigation Drawer Activity]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have selected Navigation Drawer activity while creating new project Android studio would have by default created the file app_bar_main.xml file

You should be able to find the below code given by default

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Replace the above code with below code to get search view within toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

<SearchView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: Great! How to add default title to the searchview? `android:title="Search"` not working.